# Background Tag HTML application.html.erb

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to create an `application.html.erb` file that holds a background that will be displayed on all of my pages.

Using the w3school's guide, I put the filename of the background (which is in the same folder as `application.html.erb`) in the body tag and it does not change anything.

```
<body background='bk.jpg'>
  The content goes here
</body>
```

Any help solving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Rails project, the best approach is to use [`image_path`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper/image_path).

In your case, something like the following should work:

```
<%= image_path 'path_to_your_image/bk.jpg' %>
```

However, the correct way to do this is to store the image in the projects `app/assets/images` folder, and the asset path will look for this there. Then, you just need to update the helper to:

```
<%= image_path 'bk.jpg' %>
```

So:

```
<body background=<%= image_path 'bk.jpg' %>>
# Might need quotes around this: <%= image_path 'bk.jpg' %>, haven't been able to test
```

Or, better:

```
<%= content_tag :body, style: { background: image_path('bk.jpg') } do %>
  Your content
<% end %>
```

Better still would be to have the css background set in the CSS rather than inline, though that's perhaps another question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and helpful formatting!

Comment: You're welcome, happy to help - I'd recommend having a read through the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) docs. There's a fair bit going on / you can use :)